# R transform data frame (group by)

Tags: r, plyr, reshape2

I am an R and Stack Overflow newbie so hope I'm following protocol here.

How do I transform a data frame like:

```
FRUIT   NUMBER  NAME    AGE
apples  5       Joe     13
oranges 6       Joe     13
apples  2       Mary    10
oranges 4       Mary    10
```

into a grouped data fame like:

```
NAME    AGE  APPLES ORANGES
Joe     13   5       6
Mary    10   2       4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Thanks for posting a minimal example data set and your expected answer, Since you are mentioning an SO protocol, you may read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). People are generally much more willing to help if you show that you have tried yourself, i.e. the code you have tried so far and why it didn't work. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `dcast` from package `reshape2`.

```R
> library('reshape2')
> d <- read.table(header=T, text="FRUIT   NUMBER  NAME    AGE
+ apples  5       Joe     13
+ oranges 6       Joe     13
+ apples  2       Mary    10
+ oranges 4       Mary    10");


> dcast(d, NAME + AGE ~ FRUIT, value.var='NUMBER')
  NAME AGE apples oranges
1  Joe  13      5       6
2 Mary  10      2       4
```

This is changing data from a (somewhat) long format to deep format, you can find more details of how to approach this task [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT NAME, AGE,
      MAX(CASE WHEN FRUIT = "apples" THEN NUMBER ELSE NULL END) apples, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN FRUIT = "oranges" THEN NUMBER ELSE NULL END) oranges
      FROM d 
      GROUP BY NAME 
      ORDER BY NAME')
```

Output:

```
  NAME AGE apples oranges
1  Joe  13      5       6
2 Mary  10      2       4
```